# I have a checkbox with autopost back its causing my jquery not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, autopostback

SO basically  I am making a checkbox have two functions and keep in mind i would like the autopostback to be on so that the entire page reloads but this function still would work.

So for my code I have something like

```
$(function(){
    $(".chkclass").click(function () {
       $("#Label1").fadeOut(1000);
   });
});
```

When I check the box the page reloads which I want but the label does not fade out, I want to do this with jquery.

Comment: You need to persist state somehow. Because javascript is executed on the client the "fadeOut" functionality is discarded when the page reloads. What you can try is something like session state on the client. Something like localStorage.setItem("chckClass", "true"). Then on the page load fade the "Label1" element.

Comment: maybe, adding some time out!